# How to access const map's keys and values?

Tags: c++, constants

While adding the elements of `m2` to `m1`, if `m1` and `m2` have the same key, I try to delete the pair of `m2`. If there is no `const`, it works fine, but since there is `const`, it cannot be accessed. Please let me know what the problem is.

```cpp
void mergeContainers(map<int, int>& container1, const map<int, int>& container2)
{

  for (map<int, int>::iterator it1 = container1.begin(); it1 != container1.end(); it1++)
  {
    for (map<int, int>::iterator it2 = container2.begin(); it2 != container2.end(); it2++)
    {
      if (it1->first == it2->first)
      {
        container2.erase(it2);
      }
    }
  }
  container1.insert(container2.begin(), container2.end());
}
```

Comment: There's no way you're going to be able to call `container2.erase(it2)` if `container2` is `const`. That's modifying `container2`, period.

Comment: Sidenote: You could simplify your code a lot with the use of [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [range-based-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: You also want to be careful with loops where you mutate a container while iterating over it. In `map`'s case `erase` doesn't do things like invalidate the past-the-end iterator, but in general it's a hazardous practice. You can replace the entire inner loop with `container2.erase(it1->first);`.

Comment: instead do ... if (it1->first != it2->first)
      {
        container1.insert(*it2);
      }

Comment: Thanks for all answers!
Since I am a non-English speaking person, my English must have been poor. I just misunderstood the assignment

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++17. The merge operation is a member of the map container.

```
m_1.merge(m_2);
```